# Using OkHttp on api level less than API 21

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I was looking for the best network client to use for my app, then I landed on OkHttp or retrofit but both of them require API level 21+ and my app's current minSdkVersion is 17, So should I increase my minSdkVersion to API 21 or should I use OkHttp 3.12.x branch, and if you have any other solution I want to hear your thoughts.

Please note that on the OkHttp website they said:

> "The OkHttp 3.12.x branch supports Android 2.3+ (API level 9+) and
>   Java 7+. **These platforms lack support for TLS 1.2 and should not be
>   used**. But because upgrading is difficult we will backport critical
>   fixes to the 3.12.x branch through December 31, 2021."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you decide to support clients older than 21 you should do a couple of things

1. Drop back to OkHttp 3.12.12 which will continue to get security fixes.
2. Help to secure these older clients as much as possible as they are both insecure themselves, and keep your server less secure because of retaining support for older ciphers etc.

In your build file

```
  implementation 'org.conscrypt:conscrypt-android:2.4.0'
```

And activate Conscrypt before your request

```
import org.conscrypt.Conscrypt


Security.insertProviderAt(Conscrypt.newProvider(), 1)
val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().build()

val request = Request.Builder().url("https://status.datadoghq.com/").build()
client.newCall(request).execute().use { response ->
  println(response.code())
}
```

This should allow your older clients to support TLSv1.2.

You will probably need to downgrade Retrofit as well, but I'm not sure what the correct advice is there.  Maybe to 2.6.4?

https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: but what do think about using httpurlconnection or volley?

Comment: No idea, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to increase minSdkVersion, because retrofit depends on special library.

Although if you don't want to increase the api, you can use asyntask to call service

Example

```
package principal.example;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Post extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    private InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    private BufferedReader bufferedReader;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params){

        try {
            URL obj = new URL(params[0]);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
            con.setRequestMethod("GET");
            con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", " ");
            con.connect();
            inputStreamReader=new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream());
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
            return bufferedReader.readLine();
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Url  doInBackground", e.toString());
            return null;
        } finally {
            try {
                closeConnection();
            } catch(Exception e){

            }
        }

    }

    private void closeConnection() {
        try {
            if(bufferedReader!=null){
                bufferedReader.close();
            }

            if(inputStreamReader!=null){
                inputStreamReader.close();
            }
        }catch(IOException ex){
            Log.d("Url disconnect", ex.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```